# Is considering one Prophet more virtuous than the other falls under distinction?

Tags: prophets, belief, messengers

I know that Allah raised certain Prophets status and preferred some over the other. But on the basis of this saying that because that Prophet was more noble and virtuous or saying more specifically that He committed less sins(minor) than the other. Is it Right? Obviously all Prophets are holy and infallible. But does considering one more infallible than the other falls under the verse "We make no distinction amongst the Prophets"?

Comment: @UmH No. My question was making distinction with respect to their infallibility. Is it forbidden?

Comment: The verse 'we make no distinction' is irrelevant since it means that we do not disbelieve in some prophets unlike the Jews and Christians. This is readily apparent if you read the verses in context: [2:135-136](https://quran.com/2/135-136?translations=20) and [4:150-152](https://quran.com/4/150-152?translations=20) and
[3:83-85](https://quran.com/3/83-85?translations=20). 


However what you are stating comes under disrespect of the prophets and speaking about religion without knowledge from revelation. Both of which are haram.

Comment: What is "more infallible" even supposed to mean? Someone is either infallible, or not.

Comment: @goldPsuedo sorry my English is not that good what I meant was saying like this person makes less mistakes than the other and on the basis of this drawing comparison and giving priority to one over the other.